# unable to use session variables outside view function

Tags: flask

I  have   login page   where   the  user  inputs  the  username  and password. I have  made the  username  as  session  variable in the /login  view function and would like  to use  this variable  outside   the view function in the   main  body  of the   code in   a    if-else   block.

```
session['username'] = request.form['username'].lower()
```

How  do I   do this?

Here   is   part of the  code  for  this:

```
import os
import csv
import pymysql
import pymysql.cursors
from datetime import date
import calendar
import ssl
from ldap3 import Connection, Server, ANONYMOUS, SIMPLE, SYNC, ASYNC,ALL
from flask import Flask, make_response,render_template,url_for,redirect,request,session,escape
from validusers import users

app = Flask(__name__)
IT = pymysql.connect(host='xx.xx.xx.xx', user='xxxxx', password='xxxxx',
             db='xxxx')#Connect  to the IT database
Others = pymysql.connect(host='xxxxx', user='xxxxxx', password='xxxxxx',
             db='xxxxx')#Connect to the non IT database
a=IT.cursor() # Open Cursor for IT  database
b=Others.cursor()#Open Cursor for non-IT  database
**@app.route('/')
@app.route('/login',methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    error=None
    if request.method =='POST':

        #if not request.form['username']:
            #error='You  forgot to enter "Username", please  try again'
            #return render_template('login.html',error=error)
        if request.form['username'].lower() not in users:
            error='You are not authorized to view this page !!'
            return render_template('login.html',error=error)

        #if not request.form['password']:
            #error='You  forgot to enter "Password", please  try again'
            #return render_template('login.html',error=error)
        #else:
            #s = Server('appauth.corp.domain.com:636', use_ssl=True, get_info=ALL)
            #c = Connection(s,user=request.form['username'],password=request.form['password'],check_names=True, lazy=False,raise_exceptions=False)
            #c.open()
            #c.bind()
            #if (c.bind() != True) is True:
                #error='Invalid credentials. Please try again'
            #else:
                #session['username'] = request.form['username'].lower()
                #return redirect(url_for('index'))

    return render_template('login.html',error=error)**



@app.route('/index',methods=['GET','POST'])
def index():
    if 'username' in session:
        return render_template('index.html')



Filename = os.getenv("HOMEDRIVE") + os.getenv("HOMEPATH") + "\\Desktop\RosterUnified.csv" # Create/write  a CSV file  in the  user's desktop
Filename1=os.getenv("HOMEDRIVE") + os.getenv("HOMEPATH") + "\\Desktop\RosterCurrentMonth.csv"
d=open(Filename, 'w',newline='\n') #Format for CSV  input
c = csv.writer(d)
c.writerow(["Manager NT ID"," Vertical Org","Employee ID" ]+ dayssl)# Write  the  header list of strings  in the  first row
for row in result_IT:
    c.writerow(row)#Write output for IT to csv
d.close()

#result_IT  and result_Oters  part  of code   is ommitted
e=open(Filename, 'a',newline='\n')

f= csv.writer(e)
for row in result_Others:
    f.writerow(row)# Append to the  existing  CSV file with non IT data 
e.close()

x=session['username']
sql="select verticalorg from tbl_employeedetails where empntid=(%s)"
args=x
a.execute(sql,args)
b.execute(sql,args)
c=a.fetchall()
d1=b.fetchall()
s=c+d1
q=[x[0]  for x in s]
sql1="select role from tbl_employeedetails where empntid=(%s)"
a.execute(sql1,args)
b.execute(sql1,args)
c1=a.fetchall()
d2=b.fetchall()
Role=c1+d2
r=[x[0]  for x in Role]
if r=='O':
    if q==27:
        f1=open(Filename,'r',newline='\n')
        f2=open(Filename1,'w',newline='\n')
        reader = csv.DictReader(f1)
        writer = csv.writer(f2)
        writer.writerow(["Manager NT ID"," Vertical Org","Employee ID" ]+ dayssl)
        rows = [row for row in reader if row['Vertical Org'] == 'HR']
        writer.writerow[row in rows]
    elif q==2:
        f1=open(Filename,'r',newline='\n')
        f2=open(Filename1,'w',newline='\n')
        reader = csv.DictReader(f1)
        writer = csv.writer(f2)
        writer.writerow(["Manager NT ID"," Vertical Org","Employee ID" ]+ dayssl)

    f2.close()
    z=open(Filename1)
    with z as f:
        p = f.read()

else:
    z=open(Filename)
    with z as f:
        p = f.read()

@app.route('/csv/')  
def download_csv(): 
    csv = p
    response = make_response(csv)
    cd = 'attachment; filename=RosterCurrentMonth.csv'
    response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = cd 
    response.mimetype='text/csv'

    return response
z.close()
os.remove(Filename)
@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
    # remove the username from the session if it's there
    session.pop('username', None)
    return redirect(url_for('login'))
app.secret_key ='secret key generated'
if __name__=='__main__':
    context=('RosterWeb.crt','RosterWeb.key')
    app.run(ssl_context=context, threaded=True, debug=True)
```

getting the   error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "roster.py", line 175, in <module>
    x=session['username']
  File "C:\Users\dasa17\Envs\r_web\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\local.py", line 37
3, in <lambda>
    __getitem__ = lambda x, i: x._get_current_object()[i]
  File "C:\Users\dasa17\Envs\r_web\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\local.py", line 30
2, in _get_current_object
    return self.__local()
  File "C:\Users\dasa17\Envs\r_web\lib\site-packages\flask\globals.py", line 37,
 in _lookup_req_object
    raise RuntimeError(_request_ctx_err_msg)
RuntimeError: Working outside of request context.

This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
an active HTTP request.  Consult the documentation on testing for
information about how to avoid this problem.
```

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41081041/edit) your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @dim   added    part  of the   code

Comment: You can't have a session without a request. Sessions can be active for any number of clients at a time. Without a request, Flask can't know which session to associate with `session`. That code will need to be moved somewhere that is only triggered through a request (e.g., a function called by an endpoint).

Comment: @dim  the  login view  function   is   using request. I need   to run a  function that  uses   session variable   for username in login view function to  process  data(generate csv)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to place the code you want to run before any routing is done in a function and use the [`before_first_request` decorator](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/api/#flask.Flask.before_first_request) on it. It will be executed before your first request is done and you can make use of your session variable from there.

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    # ... index route here ...
    pass

@app.before_first_request
def init_app():
    # ... do some preparation here ...
    session['username'] = 'me'
```

Comment: could   you   you please  modify part   of the   code  and put it here, I am  getting the error  saying
builtins.KeyError
KeyError: 'username'
File "C:\Users\dasa17\r_web\RosterWeb\RosterWeb\roster.p
y", line 60, in before_request
x=session['username']

Comment: where  do I call   before_request()  function ?

Comment: shouldn't  I  be using   the app.after_request     decorator instead  because    I am using the username passed  in the login  form to the  logic in the   program, am confused

Comment: The `after_request` decorator makes a function run after each request. The way your code is written it will be executed only once right away when you start your script. To get this behavior use `before_first_request`.